# error in socket.io code execution

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, server

From the Digital Ocean Community at this url, https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-express-a-node-js-framework-and-set-up-socket-io-on-a-vps, I encounter an eroor when trying to execute Part 4: The Server Code. The article states "Go and open up the app.js file in the Express application folder. Inside you'll a bunch of auto-generated code, delete all of it and use the following example instead:"

Here is the code:

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , http = require('http');

var app = express();
var server = app.listen(3000);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server); // this tells socket.io to use  `our express server`

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

app.get('/', routes.index);


console.log("Express server listening on port 3000");
```

When I make these changes to app.js and then try to execute the app I get the following error:

```
/root/socketio-test/app.js:9
var app = express();
          ^
TypeError: object is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/socketio-test/app.js:9:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

I have no idea how to correct this error.

System info: Ubuntu LEMP on 14.04
node.js installed, express installed, socket.io installed.

Comment: I don't see where the line of code `var app = express.create();` that the error refers to is in  your code.  `app.configure()` is old code from earlier versions of Express.  I'd guess you're looking at an outdated tutorial.

Comment: I found one suggestion to change line 9 from express(); to express.create(); The above  error comes from that attempt. When  line 9 is var app = express(); then the error isvar app = express();
          ^
TypeError: object is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/socketio-test/app.js:9:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3

Comment: Multi-line messages like this are impossible to read in a comment.  I'd suggest you edit your question to show the error that matches with the code you show.  You may also want to check that the Express module is properly installed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have some how installed the wrong version of express..

Do a `express --version` before `express 3.x` express was not a function.

I tried to install `npm install express -g` on a new droplet and I cannot get express to be an executable.

As far as I understand the express skeleton generator was moved into a separate package which can be installed using `npm install express-generator -g`

Which will give you the command line executable `express`, after you install `express-generator` you should be good to go.

http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html

I think DO needs to update their tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Datsik. My express version is 2.5.8. I followed your advice but the error persists.

Comment: @user2962990 you need express version 3.0 or greater

Comment: Thank you Datsik. I found that changing var app = express(); to var app = express.createServer(); solves the problem on the version installed.